# How can i limit the amount of tabs allowed open in tab panel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabpanel

What i want to do is limiting the amount of allowed tabs in a tabpanel. After a quick research, found beforeadd listener of xtype: 'tabpanel'. I could limit the amount of tabs but it's not working correctly. For example after 6 tabs, it gives an alert and doesn't allow (rejects) the open tab x. After closing couple of tabs, when i try to reopen tab x, nothing happens. But it has to open because maximum tab amount is not reached. When i try to open  tab y it's working again. Simply it doesn't let to open 'rejected' tabs no matter what. I am using extjs version 4.2 and here is my code.

```
{
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                region: "center",
                id: 'pageBrowser',
                name: 'pageBrowser',
                listeners: {
                    beforeadd: function(tp, c, index) {
                        if(tp.items.length == 6){
                            Ext.Msg.alert('The Maximum Tab Amount Has Been Reached','Please Close One Of Unused Tabs And Try Again');
                            return false;
                    },
                    add:function(tp,c,index){
                    },
                    remove: function(tp, c) {
                        c.hide();
                        if(tp.items.getCount()==0){
                            tp.activeTab=null;
                            tp.layout.activeItem=null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        };
```

Comment: [I cannot reproduce your problem with the code you provided.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1e52)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Alexander . I figured that out. The onPageSelect function in controller was causing this error.